# HTML canvas byte array to Image in java

Tags: java, arrays, image, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

Actual image

[image: Actual graph]

Generated Image

[image: Generated graph]

I have multiple Graphs (say 14 max) which are generated using Javascript(SAP/Open-UI-5) at client side I have converted these graphs into bytes array below is the code for the same

**JavaScript code**

```js
var arrCanvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
var arrImageByte = [];
for(var i=0; i<arrCanvas.length; i++){
  var canvas = arrCanvas[i];
  if(canvas.width!=0 && (typeof imageNames[i] != 'undefined')){
    var imageDetail = {};
    var uint8Array = canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height).data;
    imageDetail.byteData = [].slice.call(uint8Array);
    imageDetail.name = imageNames[i];
    imageDetail.height = canvas.height;
    imageDetail.width = canvas.width;
    arrImageByte.push(imageDetail);
  }
}
```

Now I am sending these bytes to server side using REST API and AJAX call
and creating the images on the server side below is the code where I am recreating the images

**Java code**

```java
int width = imageDetail.getWidth();
int height = imageDetail.getHeight();
byte[] data = imageDetail.getByteData();
String name = imageDetail.getName();
BufferedImage bufferedImage =new BufferedImage(width,height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
  for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    // calculate array offset
    final int o = (x * 3) + (y * width * 3);
    // set the pixel color here we will need to convert the byte
    // data to an unsigned
    // value using &0xFF before passing it to the Color
    // constructor
    bufferedImage.setRGB(x, y, new Color(data[o + 1] & 0xFF, data[o + 2] & 0xFF, data[o + 3] & 0xFF).getRGB());
  }
}

boolean result = ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", new File(baseReportFolderLocation+name+".jpg"));
logger.info("Name "+name+" status :: "+result);
```

But the color of my Image is not the same as expected. How can I recreate the image with exact same color as it was when it was created on the client side?

I have also tried the below code

```
byte[] data = imageDetail.getByteData();
        String name = imageDetail.getName();        
        BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
        ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "jpg", new File(baseReportFolderLocation+"New_"+name+".jpg"));
```

the last line throws the exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(ImageTypeSpecifier.java:925)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.getWriter(ImageIO.java:1592)
```

Comment: Why are you setting `bufferedImage.setRGB()` manually as you said the image is already created on client and it's bytes are sent to java code.??

Comment: @MadMan because the byte array from the client side is not of a compatible type with ImageTO.write throws a [B to [I conversion error. Do you know how shall I get the desired result?

Comment: @MadMan  I am getting the same issue. Have u guys found any solution?

Comment: What is the full package name of `ImageIO`??

Comment: @MadMan package javax.imageio

Comment: niharika and @Hades I have solution.. can you guys just provide your byte array response..?? Or just tell me, the byte array is base 64 encoded or not??

Comment: @Nope its not at least in my case since when I did canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData it return byte uint8array which is being copied to a new signed array from 0-255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed the code that you have described (Thank you as it helps me analyzing the problem I was facing and I have followed the similar approach ), after doing the below changes in java code I made the image exactly as that of the original image

```
int width = imageDetail.getWidth();
            int height = imageDetail.getHeight();
            byte[] data = imageDetail.getByteData();
            String name = imageDetail.getName();
            BufferedImage bufferedImage =new BufferedImage(width,height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                    int o = (x * 4) + (y * width * 4);
                    bufferedImage.setRGB(x, y, new Color(data[o] & 0xFF, data[o + 1] & 0xFF, data[o + 2] & 0xFF).getRGB());
                }
            }   
            try {
                ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", new File(PDFReportingUtil.baseReportFolderLocation+name+".jpg"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                PDFReportingUtil.logger.error("Error while executing the thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" ",e);
            }
```

Comment: see my answer if it can remove unnecessary loops and manual work of image recreation... :)

Comment: @Hades This works perfectly .. didn't know such a small issue was causing a huge trouble, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution, avoiding loops and all manual work.!!

**Required :** `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` class. So add this to your classpath.

If using Maven, add below dependency to your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

If using `jar` for dependencies, add following jar file in your `lib` or classpath.

[Apache Commons Codec Jar File](http://central.maven.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.jar)

**Solution:**

Following is my image, that I'm going to recreate using `byte array`.

[image: ACTUAL_IMAGE_IN_PNG_FORMAT]

Notice the color:-

- Dimension : 50px * 20px
- Background - White
- M - Black
- A - Yellow
- N - Green
- O - Blue
- J - Orange

It is just to verify that different colors are retained properly.

**Code**

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    String abs = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAUCAIAAABAqPnNAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACx\n" +
            "jwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAIBSURBVEhL7ZW9SgNREIXzBD5EGt8hjdhZSAqf\n" +
            "QVIkkC5gZ5VSWAg2IbUQtrJZSBGDIEQhXVAIN1FCcBtZCwstx/m7u3d/VAQ1Ch4uZGZuYD/OmU1K\n" +
            "8Cv1j/UZ/SEs41VKqIpndCAKajQt1QLtv1YPPTjchOOedAVYSpUBUKjvooLzPcI6v5MujxVTuQQW\n" +
            "6tuoMsphJVQxAo8qFZrraA73DZhuwBUf0+EhKzwqn+6WJ3530qTitNkK9Qa1HIft+mRrh099caFj\n" +
            "m6B/pm0eS6hqNXJHGATK85IJPHeIZtoA01CyiOcAwwmi0KmOBGu3PPJv+WrZvxag/bot+i98YxO8\n" +
            "0Q6VwVKqQFmMhTKcYlGC99sO1mWLUI6GT9ypc5dUr8J9cihc8g2MFw7WHRxvwuEB16o0lqWyNAF9\n" +
            "2NahmkM00ENRNnTMHNXZSrrbGRkmIYpV7TFfZNpcgqgUVvJ0qUhJp1SG7XGPGfCFJNjsilWw6o7Y\n" +
            "OapfTmil4mVKt7kEUS6W83SL5TRcRrxM0Zy+jsonaDcJnvzqGwmKVe8kiHKw0p54uPYB/566c8P2\n" +
            "yLJPxbaPE1QsOtdaxEtWlCAqweKnZ3/ZUSnaiN9BOtv6Gn6cIGnZX8Rk7f6jMqGKEkSlV/6nVZwg\n" +
            "an1YNz3w2apcgqh1YYlP+N9cYBVqvSG+qV+JBfAKOyszW/bU2FMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";

    byte [] sam = abs.getBytes(); // your bytes data goes here.. no need to create string and bytes from it. I did it for demo.
    byte [] data = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(sam);
    FileOutputStream imageOutFile = new FileOutputStream(
            "i-love-sample.jpg");
    imageOutFile.write(data);
    imageOutFile.close();
    System.out.println("Image Successfully Manipulated!");

}
```

The output will be exactly same image, but I've converted it into `jpg` (see in code), so the image is now jpg. You can specify any format you want.

**Output image:**

[image: OUTPUT_IMAGE_IN_JPG_FORMAT]

See the colors, same are recreated without loss.

Now, as I can understand, you are receiving `byte` array from client, so follow the comment in above code. You are done. No need to use even `javax.imageio.ImageIO`.

Hope it helped...!!

Comment: Thank you @Mad Man for the answer but i want the byte conversion to happen at client side since multiple such base64 decoded string (almost 15) takes a huge lot of time in conversion (Though I have implemented thread in there conversion) the approach I am using is very  quite fast (almost a difference by 15-20 secs) per image.

Comment: Though I dont have enough reputation to upvote ur answer and I can accept only one as the answer working for me.

Comment: yes, I have tried base 64 encoder it was taking almost 40 seconds to convert a single Image. Is apache decoder has a different faster way to manipulate string to bytes?

Comment: The reason behind the performance issue is that according to Java Specification, *The `char` data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character.* & *The `byte` data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer.* So for each character there wud be a function call, otherwise directly throw away first 8-bits of `char` but then data loss may occur as some of the character's don't fit into 8-bit space.